# How To Fix 503 Service Error In My Wordpress Site

Tags: http-status-code-503

How To Fix 503 Error In My Site [zybermedia.net](https://zybermedia.net) I have a wordpress site hosted on bigrock. Am also have ssl encryption in my site. From Today morning, My site not opening. It takes too much of time to display 503 error. Am not able to login to my cpanel. How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

Very first thing is you need to contact the bigrock support as they are responsible to fix this issue.

The issue is either related to memory allocation and that has to be fixed from root level.

Comment: This answer is spot on.  If you need ore details, read here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/198205/503-login-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

I got same error message today morning first time in last 5 years I've been maintaining and mastering my WordPress -platformed hobby-site. My Finnish-based Hosting-company uses "Installatron" -GUI Easy to Install WordPress -retailer version to allow customers easily to setup WordPress by couple of clicks.

I discovered from my $HOME -directory log files from my host's server, and there's a interesting lines just before my site shut down for "503 Service Unavialable" -error message.
[image]

It was not DoS -attack because of monthly bandwidth was not exceeded or wasn't larger than normal monthly traffic bandwith usage.

After Googling up some issues about this "Installatron deleteme.wp?????" -issue, I ended up that Installatron creates temporary files during installation process and some red-hat-bots can take advantage on those ones for the sabotaging WP-site.

Solution is simple: Backup your Database where your WP-site content is located on, Backup all the nessesecary files from your web host, and install WordPress manually without using Installatron -plugin retailer license versio offered by your web host company. In my opinion that prevents dark siders bots programmed by some tech-oriented red-hat humans to get your site down in that case, in my opinion

Is my real-life experience and empirical troubleshoot without host's help helping in your case? Of course first thing I did was I created support ticket to my web host's system, but they didn't answer for the my question. Second time I replied them, I attached the same Screenshot about log -file to them and now I'm waiting for new answer.